# Sequelize association functions not available - IntellIj issue

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, sequelize.js

**Update**

This morning I wanted to use another inbuilt sequelize function and suddenly the belongsTo() and hasMany() functions were available and working on some models -not all! These models have all exactly the same pattern and only differ in name.

For example `hasOne` is not available for topicClass

[image]

I didn't change anything else. Except I restarted intelliJ. I did restart it before I opened this question and always had the same issue. So I think this issue is IDE based! Still would appreciate a tip how to avoid this

---

I have an APP using sequelize with SQLite.

When I want to setup the associations in my `db-controller.js` it tells me that the association functions like `belongsTo` and `hasmany` from the [docu](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html) are not available.

When I execute the `setupAssociations` function and check the db later there are the models but no associations set.

Here the `db-controller.js` (more info from my side after the models at the bottom!)

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const userModel = require('../model/user')
const subjectModel = require('../model/subject')
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const initUser = userModel.user.initUser()
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const initSubject = subjectModel.subject.initSubject()
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: './user.sqlite',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
  logging: false
})
sequelize.sync()

function setupAssociations(){
  // user + subject
  userModel.user.userClass.hasMany(subjectModel.subject.subjectClass)
  subjectModel.subject.subjectClass.belongsTo(userModel.user.userClass)
  // subject + topic
}

function testAssociations(){
  setupAssociations()
}

testAssociations()
```

and my two models

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: '../controller/user.sqlite',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
  logging: false
})
sequelize.sync()

/**
 * User Model
 */
class User extends Sequelize.Model {
}


/**
 * Init user model
 */

function initUser () {
  //TODO optional realize with sequelize.transaction
  User.init(
    // attributes
    {
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    // options
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'user'
    }
  )

}

/**
 * Makes functions available globally
 */
exports.user = {
  initUser: initUser,
  userClass: User
}
```

and Subject

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: '../controller/user.sqlite',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
  logging: false
})
sequelize.sync()

/**
 // * Subject Model
 */
class Subject extends Sequelize.Model {
}

/**
 * Initialises subject model
 */
function initSubject () {
  Subject.init(
    // attributes
    {
      subjectName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    // options
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'subject'
    }
  )
}

/**
 * Makes functions globally available
 */
exports.subject = {
  initSubject: initSubject,
  subjectClass: Subject
}
```

If I create another class like `class TestClass extends Sequelize.Model` in the `user.js` file and call `hasMany` with `belongsTo` within the `initUser` function and check the db after, then everything is as I want it to.

So what I do here wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I had from another project a script running adding to the comment of the export function

```
@type {{initTopic: (function(): Promise<*>), topicClass: Topic}}
```

This caused the issue. Removing it made all sequelize functions appearing again.